# remove an elements ability to open a modal after first click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a square that opens like a door when you click it. I also have a data attribute attached to it, which opens a modal. So basically the door opens and reveals a modal.

What I want, is to show the animation, open the modal ONCE, then disable it.

```
$(document).on("click", function(){
    $('.door_1').addClass('doorOpen');
});
```

```html
<div class="door_1" id="door_1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1"></div>
```

Adding the doorOpen class is what triggers the door opening animation. So is there a way to remove the data-attribute after the initial click?

Comment: I did that, still happens.

Comment: You should provide a minimalistic sample replicating your issue

Comment: Have you looked at `.one()`? http://api.jquery.com/one/ - it does exactly what you want I think, if I understand you correctly

Comment: Create snippet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example how to open only once the modal..

We first watch for event `hidden.bs.modal` on modal, that happens when modal is closed, and then we only need to removing `data-toggle` attr from button that initiates the modal!
All events for bootstrap modal are documented here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events

```js
// after modal is closed, remove attached events
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('button').attr('data-toggle', '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Some Lorem Ipsum ..
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an animation with setTimeOut like below:

```
$('.door_1').addClass('doorOpen');
setTimeout(function () {
  $('#modal-1').modal('hide');
  $('.door_1').removeClass('doorOpen');
}, 1000);
```

This will close the modal after 1 second or 1000 milliseconds.